# Protractor jasmine2-protractor-util TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0

I've got a problem with separated protractor specs. I've trying to divide 1 test 1 spec. And got a error message like

`E/launcher - Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
 E/launcher - TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at C:\Users\mako\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jasmine2-protractor-utils\reporter\jasmine2_reporter.js:112:24
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at self.jasmineDone (C:\Users\mako\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jasmine2-protractor-utils\reporter\jasmine2_reporter.js:108:16)
    at dispatch (C:\Users\mako\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1966:28)
    at ReportDispatcher.jasmineDone (C:\Users\mako\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1
949:11)
    at C:\Users\mako\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:758:18
    at QueueRunner.clearStack (C:\Users\mako\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:660:9)
    at QueueRunner.run (C:\Users\mako\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1881:12)
    at C:\Users\mako\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1898:16
    at C:\Users\mako\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1842:9
 E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199`

Test cases are running properly, error happens after all suites are done.
Problem disappear if spec have more than on "it" even empty. Have you got any ideas what can be a problem?

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: post your config file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a piece of code which returns a promise , to your onPrepare block of Protractor configuration file.

For Example:

```
onPrepare: function () {

        // returning the promise makes protractor wait for the reporter config before executing tests 
        return global.browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) {

        });
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I "solve" problem.

`/*plugins: [{
        package: 'jasmine2-protractor-utils',
        disableHTMLReport: false,
        disableScreenshot: false,
        screenshotPath:'./test_results/E2E/screenshots',
        screenshotOnExpectFailure:true,
        screenshotOnSpecFailure:true,
        clearFoldersBeforeTest: true,
        htmlReportDir: './test_results/E2E/htmlReports',
        /*failTestOnErrorLog: {
                    failTestOnErrorLogLevel: 900,
                    excludeKeywords: ['keyword1', 'keyword2']
                }*/
    //  }],`

And the problem is with plugin 'jasmine2-protractor-utils'. If I've got two specs and one test each error happens. Without this plugin or if I add empty test to one of them it works fine.